# Problem with using two-level template in C++

Tags: c++

The following code fails to compile. Why is that?

```
template<typename T, class C>
class ExPack_BASE_t
{
    Ex::u32 packageDestination = Ex::command_registration;
    Ex::u16 amoutOfParameters = (sizeof(C)/sizeof(T))-((sizeof(Ex::u32)+sizeof (Ex::u16)));
};


template<typename T>
class ExPack_registration_st : ExPack_BASE_t<T,ExPack_registration_st>
{
    T *firstName;
    T *secondName;
    T *fatherName;
    T *emil;

    T *birthDate;

    T *login;
    T *password;
    T *rePassword;
};
```

When I try to compile it I have the error:

`use of class template 'ExPack_registration_st' requires template arguments`

Problem occurred with `ExPack_BASE_t<T,ExPack_registration_st>` when using `ExPack_registration_st`

Comment: That's not enough information. At least you should tell us the exact error message. Also you should provided a [mcve], as I don't think we'll be able to help otherwise.

Comment: The second template argument you are passing is `ExPack_registration_st`, but this is the name of a `template`, not a type. Try passing `ExPack_registration_st<T>` as the second argument.

Comment: Full error: `D:\WinFiles\Documents\ExClient\exserverpackettype.h:47: error: use of class template 'ExPack_registration_st' requires template arguments`

Comment: Bitwize, you are a genius!)) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second template argument you are passing is ExPack_registration_st, but this is the name of a template, not a type. Try passing ExPack_registration_st as the second argument. – Bitwize